# A package is not recognized in MyEclipse

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, myeclipse

I have created an EE project in MyEclipse.

I have one jsp file under "WebRoot" and it contains the following lines:

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*,java.sql.*,com.sp.model.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
  <html>
     <body>
      <%
         String username=request.getParameter("username");
         String password=request.getParameter("passwd");

         UserBeanCL ubc=new UserBeanCL();
       %>
 ...
```

and I have also created a package called com.sp.model under "src" in MyEclipse.As you can see from the first line of the JSP code above, I have imported that package using import statement.UserBeanCL is just a normal JAVA class sits under that package, nothing special. Everything looks good in MyEclipse.It does find the package and the UserBeanCL class.

However, after I deployed the whole site into Tomcat and try run this JSP in browser, it always gives error and complains about line:

```
UserBeanCL ubc=new UserBeanCL();
```

The error is like: "UserBeanCL cannot be resolved to a type". The stacktrace is:

```
Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:469)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

This error is confusing to me, since it only appears after deployment. Could experts help me on where to debug? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*,java.sql.*,com.sp.model.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
```

Regards;

Answer (score 0):

The editor in MyEclipse will usually create separate import statements for each type, if you let it. That is, the following statement would be added, in your case:

> <%page import="com.sp.model.UserBeanCL">

I'm not sure that this will help as I couldn't replicate your problem, but it might help if there are more messages in your console than you posted, as the primary cause may be some parsing problem, which would show up in earlier console messages.